# Hibernate ignores FetchType for Single Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetching-strategy

I have 3 entities inheriting from another entity.
I'm using the strategy Single_Table

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

E.g. Class B,C and D inherite from A

On entity B I'm loading another entity X eagerly. Unfortunately, Hibernate ignores my annotation and creates a select for each entity B to fetch entity X.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Projekt projekt;
```

My select statement looks as follows:
    ´select a from A a´

Some more code examples:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 3)
public abstract class A {}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(B.PREFIX)
public class B extends A {

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private Projekt projekt;
}
```

Now I expect Hibernate to query all classes which inherite from A, which it does. Unfortunately it also executes a select statement for each result row to query "projekt", which I want to avoid.

Comment: Your select statement is not valid JPQL. Are you sure it's not "select a from A a"? If Hibernate generates a select to fetch X for each B, then it does not ignore your annotation: X is fetched eagerly.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the example. I tried to make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't insert joins into SQL queries generated from the HQL/JPQL ones for `FetchType.EAGER`.

In order to insert `join` you need to specify `left join fetch` explicitly, I guess it won't create problems for `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` despite the fact that this relationship doesn't exists in other subclasses:

```
from A a left join fetch a.projekt
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to do?  If you do "from A" - then it is fetching entities of all the inherited types. It is not possible (or atleast not easy) to create a sql query that fetching B,C,D and then for B fetch X eagerly.What do you want it to do?

To avoid many queries you can set the BatchSize on the association. That will optimize loading of Xs in batches - instead of one query for each B.

If you are only interested in B entities you can write the query as "from B"  in which case the association will be eagerly fetched.

Comment: I updated the question. I want to fetch all entries. This works correctly. But I don't want another select statement for each row of Type B to query the member projekt. I tried to use all those annotations but they will be ignored.